# Why function if/else not work in Datatables CI (use Ignited)

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I get this library datatbles on git hub, this is ignited datatbles.

Ok, i've code in my Controller,

```
function json_survey(){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->load->library('Datatables');
        $this->load->helper('datatables_helper');
        $this->datatables->SELECT('id_survey,judul_survey,status_survey,responden,detail_target,judul_kategori,judul_target');
        $dataids = array('id_survey'=> '$1','status_survey'=> '$2');
        $this->datatables->add_column('action',tombol_survey($dataids), 'id_survey,status_survey');
        $this->datatables->FROM('survey');
        $this->datatables->JOIN('kategori','survey.id_kategori=kategori.id_kategori');
        $this->datatables->JOIN('target','survey.id_target=target.id_target');


        return print_r($this->datatables->generate('json',''));
    }
```

And i have code in muy Helper to create button with function if/else

```
function tombol_survey($ids)
    {
        $ci = & get_instance();
        if(!empty($ids)){
            $html = '<span class="actions">';
            if($ids['status_survey']=='terbit'){ 
                $html .= '<a href="' . base_url() . 'survey/edit/'.$ids['id_survey'].'">Tutup</a>';
            }
            if($ids['status_survey']=='tertunda'){
                $html .= '<a href="' . base_url() . 'pertanyaan/tambah/'.$ids['id_survey'].'">Tambah</a>';
            }
            if($ids['status_survey']=='tutup'){
                $html .= 'Hapus | ';
            }
            $html .= '<a href="' . base_url() . 'pertanyaan/tambah/' .$ids['id_survey']. '">Test</a>';
            $html .= '</span>';

            return $html;
        }
    }
```

my problem, function if not work but 2 parameter (id_survey & status_survey) was inclued.
Please help me sir

Look my picture
[image: Pic]

Comment: You need to debug - $dataids - Use var_dump($dataids) and check it...

Comment: What does $html return?

Comment: html return is return code of button <a href=.....

Comment: value of dataids is id_survey and status_survey from database

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Muhammad Rizki,

You have to check ids format first how it will come in function. You have to use json_decode to convert JSON data into array. then you can access values using $ids['status_survey'].

example :

```
$ids = json_decode($ids);
```

Thanks

Comment: but in this code (add_coloumn) data not yet covert to jsson code, convert to json code in the last line

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform some simple debugging...

You have this line

```
$dataids = array('id_survey'=> '$1','status_survey'=> '$2');
```

If you perform a var_dump on this like...

```
$dataids = array('id_survey'=> '$1','status_survey'=> '$2');
var_dump($dataids);
```

you will get

```
array (size=2)
  'id_survey' => string '$1' (length=2)
  'status_survey' => string '$2' (length=2)
```

These are NOT in any of your If/Else tests so they none of them will evaluate.

Your HTML will evaluate to be

```
</pre><span class="actions"><a href="http://cidev315.com/pertanyaan/tambah/$1">Test</a></span>
```

So first thing is to change your code by removing the quotes from that line so it becomes...

```
$dataids = array('id_survey'=> $1,'status_survey'=> $2);
```

BUT I cannot see where you are setting the values for $1 and $2.

So for starters remove the quotes around $1 and $2... They are Variables - Not Strings...

Comment: error 'ParseError' sir if not quotes... on datatabes $1 is id_survey with type data integer and $2 is status_survey with type data enum sir

Comment: Use double quotes then. Double quotes will evaluate $1 and $2... Single quotes do not evaluate variables and just return the actual strings...

Comment: id_survey and status survey ($1,$2) was included, i debug form helper this value is included.... but when i modif with function if/else not work

Comment: i've a picture, you can look in here https://scontent.fsub1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/23621641_895089800648969_3365849000421620663_n.jpg?oh=105d17e908c7a03cb6a481b11fdd7b5b&oe=5AADCFDC

Comment: So where does $1 and $2 come from? What did you get when you did a var_dump($dataids); ? You might need to add in a die(); to see it...

Comment: $1 and $2 come from  $this->datatables->add_column('action',tombol_survey($dataids), 'id_survey,status_survey') or from datatbase when i select it.... and when i debug, i get it,  array(2) {
  ["id_survey"]=>
  string(2) "$1"
  ["status_survey"]=>
  string(2) "$2"
}

Comment: Ok so where in your function are you testing for when $ids['status_survey'] = '$2'? I think you are using this incorrectly from my quick readup of ignited tables. The issue is those variables are not being assigned any values when you are trying to use them.

Comment: What variable do you mean sir?

Comment: You are trying to use $1 and $2 when they don't have any values...Just because you have put them into a statement doesn't mean they get assigned anything... That seems to occur once the datatables is generated...

Comment: So any solution sir? :D